# URL for Django filtering get requests

Tags: django, filter

I'm making a filtering function for a database I'm working with. I'm wondering how I can access the request url.

Here is the code for the models.

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True)

class Interest(models.Model):
    interest = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    listing_account = models.ForeignKey(ListingAccount, related_name='interests', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.interest}"
```

Below is the filtering function in views.py. How can I find the URL path to this?

```
class AccountFilterViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ListingAccount.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListingAccountSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['first_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

URL patterns are defined in the `urls.py`. To find the URL path to the `AccountFilterViewSet` view, you need to locate `urls.py` that maps to the view. If not found, you must define it.
Example:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import AccountFilterViewSet

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', AccountFilterViewSet.as_view(), name='accounts'),
]
```

Assum you in localhost and use port 8000.

URL path of this is: `localhost:8000/accounts/`